# Maven dependency causes NoClassDefFoundError in servlet

Tags: eclipse, maven, servlets, dependencies

I have created a servlet as a Dynamic Web Project in Eclipse, then converted it to a Maven project. I initially created it as a simple “Hello World” servlet and “Run on Server” worked fine.

I then added another (Maven) project in my workspace as a dependency and referenced one of the classes in that project. Now the servlet fails with a `NoClassDefFoundError` exception as soon as a class from the dependency is referenced. What gives?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Browsing through some other question I found some helpful hints:

I tried **Run as > maven install** on the project, which failed with an error indicating my dependency could not be found. Turns out I needed to add my dependency to my local repo first—behavior is different from a standard Java application here.

Choose the dependency, then **Run as > maven install** to store the dependency in your local repository.

After that I was able to run the servlet on my server with no further issues.